# I want get checked multiple record id in yii2

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii2

I am new here can anyone tell me how to get checked record id from index for remove selected record using **Ajax** and **Jquery** this is my form and ajax script for select this code does not do any action so let me know

```
<div class="usermaster-model-index">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-info pull-right" value="Delete Multiple" id="MyButton" >
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?php
    ?>
    <p>
        <?= Html::a('Create Usermaster Model', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </p>
    <?=
    GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        //'class' => ActionColumn::className(),
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'user_fname',
            'user_id',
            'user_lname',
            'user_mobile',
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
            [ 'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
                'checkboxOptions' => ["attribute" => 'user_id'],
            ],
        ],
    ]);
    ?>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#MyButton').click(function () {
             alert('hello'); 
            var HotId = $('#user_id').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                url: Url::toRoute('usermaster/MultipleDelete'),
                data: {user_id: HotId},
                success: function () {
                 $(this).closest('tr').remove(); 
               }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

and here my controller action which delete multiple data  function to get selected id and delete

```
public function actionMultipleDelete()
{
    $data = Yii::$app->request->post('user_id');
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) 
    {
        $sql = "DELETE FROM usermaster WHERE user_id = $value";
        $query = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->execute();
    }
    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}
```

Comment: have you tried to print `HotId` array using console.log(HotId) ?.  What does it display's

Comment: yes nitin i tried but it is not working i have define id also in gridview

Answer (score 1):

In your gridview add `id` option

```
GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'id'=> your-id //set your id here and use this is in jquery
        //'class' => ActionColumn::className(),
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'user_fname',
            'user_id',
            'user_lname',
            'user_mobile',
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
            [ 'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
                'checkboxOptions' => ["attribute" => 'user_id'],
            ],
        ],
    ]);
```

and in Jquery replace  `user_id` with your new id as follows.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#MyButton').click(function () {
             alert('hello'); 
            var HotId = $('#your-id').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows'); // modify this line
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                url: Url::toRoute('usermaster/MultipleDelete'),
                data: {user_id: HotId},
                success: function () {
                 $(this).closest('tr').remove(); 
               }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i am getting alert but not getting id

Comment: @sms : is it working now? if so, please do accept the answer so the  person who answers come to know about it and it will help others also.

Comment: not any error i am deb there is no error any option nitin

Comment: well, if you inspect the code, you can see default id of grid-view something like 'w0', you can use it, once you get the selected rows  id in jquery, rest is so simple

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126023/discussion-between-nitin-and-sms).